# Creating an extension to a class?

Tags: java, class-extensions

In some languages like C# and Objective C, you can create class extensions. That means you can add additional methods to an existing class without having to extend that class. Is this possible in Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Oli mentions, it is not possible.

It is worth mentioning that an extension method in C# is just a fancy way of calling an Static method, so although it looks like

```
someobject.MyExtensionMethod();
```

then the compiler translates that to

```
SomeStaticClass.MyExtensionMethod(someobject);
```

You are not *really* adding a method to the object

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that about C#

Comment: I disagree.  Extensions really extend the class. If i, for example, add the method localization() to the String object, i can use that method with any string object. There is no need to use a derivation.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was implying, and what you say is untrue, you can only call that method if you import the namespace

Answer (score 3):

No, not with standard Java.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) that is using compile-time weaving to add to the bytecode.

Comment: I feel like using AOP for this purpose is over-engineering :)

Comment: it might be and also it's not a language construct but I'd like to mention it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a language construct, that would allow you to do that, but you could use Decorator pattern to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the lombok library. There is an annotation that is called @ExtensionMethod.

This gives you that functionality.

See https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/ExtensionMethod.html